# Use a Tcp Client in an azure function

Tags: c#, tcp, azure-functions, tcpclient

I need a small piece of code that will be triggered by an incoming HTTP call. The code will then take this information open a connection to a TCP socket. It will send the data and get a response, close the socket and send a response to the original HTTP message. Is this possible inside an Azure function? I appreciate you can't keep open a permanent TCP socket connection. This only needs to be a temporary connection to do a single request and response.

Note i don't have control over the server side that hosts the TCP socket server.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Hint: It should be possible. We establish an SMTP connection, which is a TCP connection at the end of the day.

Comment: Using a socket to do this would be efficient, but it would be living in the 1980s. Use a more scalable and reliable framework/protocol/microservice where the details are taken care of, is predictable and you only have to worry about the contract

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this as I have the same problem.  A very old on-prem system that requires XML to be sent over a socket connection.  I have a Function app integrated into a VNet that can access my on-prem address.  Firewall shows traffic getting through but still get a connection attempt failed error.  Talked to Microsoft support who said it should be fine and is an on-prem issue somewhere?  The Function App works fine locally...